# Refer tables in another schema in oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle12c

I would like to refer to multiple tables in another schema without schema prefix or altering the session.

I have the below query -

```
Select * from schema1.app_table
```

There are multiple queries like these in packages which have schema prefix.

I have to export the tables to a different schema. I really don’t want to change the schema prefix in all the packages.

I tried synonyms and unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic.

You are changing the schema in which the tables reside.
Note my use of the word "change".
This means that you must "change" everything that references the tables.

If you hate quality,
you can try this: create a synonym in the old schema that references the table in the new schema.
In your example,
lets call the new schema "blammySchema" and we will call the table "kapow".

Here are some steps:

1. "Export" all of the tables from schema1 to blammySchema (all tables that apply).
2. For every table that was "exported" to blammySchema, create a synonym in schema1 that references the table in blammySchema.

Here is a synonym example:

```
create synonym schema1.kapow for blammySchema.kapow
```

After you have created all of the synonyms,
recompile your packages.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I tried using synonyms. I need to make code changes in all packages to start referring the synonym names in quotes. Is there any other way without using synonyms?

Comment: There is exactly no requirement to use quotes when referencing a synonym in oracle.

Comment: Hi. This solution will not work for me. I cannot retain schema1.

Comment: @SurajkuamrShinde Create the synonyms in the schema that owns the package, not in schema1. You do not need quotes to use synonyms.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. The packages also will be moved to the new schema. I understand the right way to do it is to modify the packages as well. I am looking for any other way for now to not modify the packages.